# how to obtain dictionary of dictionaries that stores aggregated values from a csv file

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, aggregate, summary

I have a data file that contains the following:

```
 Part#1
         A 10 20 10 10 30 10 20 10 30 10 20
         B 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 20 30
  Part#2
         A 30 30 30 10 10 20 20 20 10 10 10
         B 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 30 10
  Part#3
         A 10 20 10 30 10 20 10 20 10 20 10
         B 10 10 20 20 20 30 10 10 20 20 30
```

From there I'm looking to have dictionary of dictionaries with summarized data per letter, so it will be something like this:

```
dictionary = {{Part#1:{A:{10:6, 20:3, 30:2},
                       B:{10:6, 20:2, 30:3}}}, 
              {Part#2:{A:{10:5, 20:3, 30:3}, 
                       B:{10:7, 20:1, 30:3}}}, 
              {Part#3:{A:{10:6, 20:4, 30:1}, 
                       B:{10:4, 20:5, 30:2}}}}
```

that way if I want to display each part it will give me an output like this:

```
dictionary[Part#1]

A
 10: 6
 20: 3
 30: 2

B
 10: 6
 20: 2
 30: 3
```

… and so on for the next couple of partitions in the file.

At the moment I've been able to parse the file from txt to csv. and convert such into a dictionary let's say the outer dictionary. I've been testing a couple of ways to see the output I get, and so far this piece of code is the one closer (but not in its entirety) to the structure I'm looking for, which I already described above.

```
partitions_dict = df_head(5).to_dict(orient='list')      

print(partitions_dict)

Output:

{0: ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], 1: ['10', '10', '10', '10', '10'], 2: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 3: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 4: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 5: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 6: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 7: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

The functions I'm using to parse the file:

```
def fileFormatConverter(txt_file):
    """ Receives a generated text file  of partitions as a parameter
        and converts it into csv format.
        input: text file
        return: csv file """

    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(txt_file)
    csv_file = filename + ".csv"
    in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"), delimiter = ' ')
    out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file,'w'))
    out_csv.writerows(in_txt)   
    return (csv_file)

# removes "Part#0" as a header from the dataframe
df_traces = pd.read_csv(fileFormatConverter("sample.txt"), skiprows=1, header=None)   #, error_bad_lines=False)
df_traces.head()
```

output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ...     15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
0   A,  10,     20,     10,     10,     30,     10,     20,     10,     30,     ...     20,     10,     10,     30,     10,     30,     10,     20,     30.0    NaN
1   Part#2  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   A,  30,     30,     30,     10,     10,     20,     20,     20,     10,     ...     20,     10,     10,     30,     10,     30,     10,     30,     10.0    NaN
3   Part#3  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   A,  10,     20,     10,     30,     10,     20,     10,     20,     10,     ...     20,     20,     20,     30,     10,     10,     20,     20,     30.0    NaN
```

I used a function to change the headers so it would be easier to manipulate the letters inside of each partition:

```
def changeDFHeaders(df):

    df_transpose = df.T
    new_header = df_transpose.iloc[0]                       # stores the first row for the header
    df_transpose = df_transpose[1:]                         # take the data less the header row
    df_transpose.columns = new_header                       # set the header row as the df header
    return(df_transpose)


# The counter column serves as an index for the entire dataframe
#df_transpose['counter'] = range(len(df_transpose))      # adds the counter for rows column
#df_transpose.set_index('counter', inplace=True)
df_transpose_headers = changeDFHeaders(df_traces)
df_transpose_headers.infer_objects()
```

Output:

```
    A,  Part#2  A,  Part#3  A,
1   10,     NaN     30,     NaN     10,
2   20,     NaN     30,     NaN     20,
3   10,     NaN     30,     NaN     10,
4   10,     NaN     10,     NaN     30,
5   30,     NaN     10,     NaN     10,
6   10,     NaN     20,     NaN     20,
7   20,     NaN     20,     NaN     10,
8   10,     NaN     20,     NaN     20,
9   30,     NaN     10,     NaN     10,
10  10,     NaN     10,     NaN     20,
11  20,     NaN     10,     NaN     10,
12  B,  NaN     B,  NaN     B,
13  10,     NaN     10,     NaN     10,
14  10,     NaN     10,     NaN     10,
15  20,     NaN     20,     NaN     20,
16  10,     NaN     10,     NaN     20,
17  10,     NaN     10,     NaN     20,
18  30,     NaN     30,     NaN     30,
19  10,     NaN     10,     NaN     10,
20  30,     NaN     30,     NaN     10,
21  10,     NaN     10,     NaN     20,
22  20,     NaN     30,     NaN     20,
23  30  NaN     10  NaN     30
24  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

--still not quite right...

and if you check this statement:

```
df = df_transpose_headers
partitions_dict = df.head(5).to_dict(orient='list')      

print(partitions_dict)
```

output:

```
{'A,': ['10,', '20,', '10,', '30,', '10,'], 'Part#2': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Part#3': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]}
```

Comment: I noticed you've edited your question to clarify why this isn't a duplicate: can you also [edit] to include what you're tried to solve this problem? Please include all the relevant code which you do have.

Comment: @TemporalWolf  thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I've cast a vote for reopening, but I don't see how you derive the output in your code from the input given at the top of your question.

Comment: @TemporalWolf ok. I'll add the functions so you can see what is doing. still not quite right though.

Comment: Thanks for responding to requests for additional information. To further improve your question, you will find the tips in [ask] and [mcve] very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an input file of:

```
  Part#1
         A 10 20 10 10 30 10 20 10 30 10 20
         B 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 20 30
  Part#2
         A 30 30 30 10 10 20 20 20 10 10 10
         B 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 30 10
  Part#3
         A 10 20 10 30 10 20 10 20 10 20 10
         B 10 10 20 20 20 30 10 10 20 20 30
```

This should work

```
def parse_file(file_name):
    return_dict = dict()
    section = str()
    with open(file_name, "r") as source:
        for line in source.readlines():
            if "#" in line:
                section = line.strip()
                return_dict[section] = dict()
                continue
            tmp = line.strip().split()
            group = tmp.pop(0)
            return_dict[section][group] = dict()
            for item in tmp:
                if item in return_dict[section][group].keys():
                    return_dict[section][group][item] += 1
                else:
                    return_dict[section][group][item] = 1

    return return_dict
```

outputs

```
{'Part#1': {'A': {'10': 6, '20': 3, '30': 2},
            'B': {'10': 6, '20': 2, '30': 3}},
 'Part#2': {'A': {'10': 5, '20': 3, '30': 3},
            'B': {'10': 7, '20': 1, '30': 3}},
 'Part#3': {'A': {'10': 6, '20': 4, '30': 1},
            'B': {'10': 4, '20': 5, '30': 2}}}
```

I honestly don't understand why you'd want an intermediate stage,  it seems like if you have to parse the file once to create a CSV, you can just put your logic to create your dict() into that. So if I missed some subtlety in the question I apologize.

Edit: reformulated answer based on comments that the input file is actually a single line

so with an input file of

```
Part#1 A 10 20 10 10 30 10 20 10 30 10 20 B 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 20 30 Part#2 A 30 30 30 10 10 20 20 20 10 10 10 B 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 30 10 Part#3 A 10 20 10 30 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 B 10 10 20 20 20 30 10 10 20 20 30
```

The following modified code will work

```
import string
from pprint import pprint

def parse_file2(file_name):
    return_dict = dict()
    section = None
    group = None
    with open(file_name, "r") as source:
        for line in source.readlines():
            tmp_line = line.strip().split()
            for token in tmp_line:
                if "#" in token:
                    section = token
                    return_dict[section] = dict()
                    continue
                elif token in string.ascii_uppercase:
                    group = token
                    return_dict[section][group] = dict()
                    continue
                if section and group:
                    if token in return_dict[section][group].keys():
                        return_dict[section][group][token] += 1
                    else:
                        return_dict[section][group][token] = 1

    return return_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pprint(parse_file(file_name))
    pprint(parse_file2(file_name2))
```

Please note that this function is specifically keyed to the file format you've noted in the comments.  If the file format is not as you say it will probably blow up.

Based on the problem though this should work.

Additionally if you can simplify the question post above to just illustrate the actual file contents, and desired results, or just put in I have structure A and want to convert it to structure B,  I'll clean up all of the history in this post and have a more simple answer as well.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: because for some reason if I do it directly the file is taken as a an object (the whole file one object)  and is more than 50k entries that's why it cannot be called directly as a text file. doing a function directly, and it didn't work. I do appreciate your help, this is a huge help... Thank you  :)!

Comment: Hmmm,  does that mean your file has no new line characters? What you describe should be the case if you use read() rather than readlines().  Furthermore it isn't clear in the question that your intermediate stage is correct. In your partition_dict function it looks like all of you lists contain nothing but 10 (except the first one which contains an A, B repeating pattern.  If you're looking for a means to convert the intermediate structure to the final structure it may remove some confusion to just illustrate. Such as: "I have structure A, and I want to morph it to this structure B"

Comment: here is thing, i shouldn't have put it in a nice format at the beginning. the file actually displays the information like this:  Part#1 A 10 20 10 10 30 10 20 10 30 10 20 B 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 20 30 Part#2 A 30 30 30 10 10 20 20 20 10 10 10 B 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 30 10 Part#3 A 10 20 10 30 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 B 10 10 20 20 20 30 10 10 20 20 30     so when reading the file as a .text file it takes the whole file as if is reading only one argument (enormous argument though) it does not recognize spaces in between. so that's why  I convert it into a csv file; it separates everyth

Comment: when  reading it directly with your function I do get a separation of two lines between A and B with the text file, when I parse it with my function into a csv and then read the csv with your function I get three lines, and those lines mess up everything, but the white space is not evident (at least in the file) and yes the the partitions are equally distributed (10 per letter)

Comment: Ah I see!  that makes more sense now.  let me restructure the answer based on this.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid pandas, simply because I don't know it very well:

```
from collections import Counter

result = {}
part = ""
group = ""
for line in f:  # f being an open file
    sline = line.strip()
    if sline.startswith("Part"):
        part = sline
        result[part] = {}
        continue
    group = sline.split()[0]
    result[part][group] = Counter(sline.split()[1:])
```

Result takes the form:

```
{'Part#1': {'A': Counter({'10': 6, '20': 3, '30': 2}), 'B': Counter({'10': 6, '30': 3, '20': 2})}, 
 'Part#2': {'A': Counter({'10': 5, '30': 3, '20': 3}), 'B': Counter({'10': 7, '30': 3, '20': 1})}, 
 'Part#3': {'A': Counter({'10': 6, '20': 4, '30': 1}), 'B': Counter({'20': 5, '10': 4, '30': 2})}}
```

---

If you're going directly from an file which is not line separated, you can use "Part" to find the lines, followed by using the index of "B" to separate the two data types:

```
result = {}
sf = f.split("Part")[1:]  # drop the empty first part
for line in sf:
    line = line.strip()  # remove trailing spaces
    sline = line.split()  # split on spaces
    result["Part%s" % sline[0]] = {}  # Use the index of B to split the value lists
    result["Part%s" % sline[0]][sline[1]] = Counter(sline[2:sline.index("B")])
    result["Part%s" % sline[0]]["B"] = Counter(sline[sline.index("B") + 1:])
```

Comment: Thank you!  I use pandas mainly to convert the file from txt to csv. the display is for checking  outputs.

Comment: I added another method which should work directly from the file if it's all one giant line. If there are more than two types (A/B) then it would need to be abstracted for a generic slice.

Comment: TemporalWolf and @sehafoc, you have no idea how much I appreciate your help. I got it to work with your methods (yey!).  I do have question though, and this is something I got question about while looking at this form. when doing the summary this way do I loose the original values, and keep only the summaries?  if that is the case then instead of calling the file every time I should keep that in a 3D matrix (would that be a better approach to keep the original values?)  I already started with the matrix to keep those values displaying is always an issue!